# Reloading a UITableView every time an app will enter foreground

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

this is more than a question, a request for advice.

How resource expensive would it be to reload a `UITableView` every time an app will enter foreground?

What I need to accomplish is to change the color of the `UILabel` inside the cells of the `UITableView` depending on the current date, however knowing average users don't normally terminate their app and simply leave it there running in the background, I would assume that the `tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method would not get called when they launch it again, and therefore, the UILabel would not update accordingly.

I know that the `reloadData` method calls the `tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.
My question is, would you advice against calling this method every time the app would enter foreground?
If so, what other alternatives do I have?

Thank you in advance.
Your help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reloadData` should only call `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` for those rows actually visible on the screen. The speed of it will mainly depend on your other UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate methods, particularly the height-related delegate methods and the data source methods listed for "Configuring a Table View" in [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

The best idea is probably to just try it and find out.

Comment: This is the answer, I do this and its not a problem.

Answer (score 2):

`reloadData` seems OK for use in your application. It wouldn't be too expensive as long as your method for retrieving that data is efficient. Don't call out your whole SQL database to an array then, get the 5 values seen on screen every time data is refreshed. As long as your not doing something like that you should be fine. You could test this though in instruments and monitor your memory usage.

Comment: Thank you, I did and memory seems to be ok.